# Has anyone experienced money wire from Bitfinex to a european bank? How are the fees applied?

Tags: transaction-fees, withdrawal, bitfinex

I try to find the best way to cash-out when needed. I use Bitfinex lately and I see that they have a good fee structure (https://www.bitfinex.com/fees - if you know something better let me know). However, I am curious that if it is the same Europe. Is there any one who experienced this and give some information regarding all the fees and disposals I need to consider?